# Kotlin, implement extension var property

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-extension

It seems that a simple extension property like the following does not work.

```
var Dog.age = 0;
```

What is the recommended way to implement this? I have tried the following, and it worked, but this will prevent any `Dog` object from cleaned up by the Garbage Collector, won't it?

```
class Dog
{
}

val dogAgeMap=HashMap<Dog, Int>();
var Dog.age:Int
    get() =  dogAgeMap[this]?: 0;
    set(value){ dogAgeMap[this] = value}

class PetShop
{
    fun work()
    {
        val d1 = Dog();
        d1.age = 100;
        val d2 = Dog();
        d2.age = 200;
        println("${d1.age}, ${d2.age}");
    }
}

fun main(args:Array<String>)
{
    PetShop().work();
}
```

Comment: Yes. More accurately, this prevents any `Dog` object that you have set the `age` of from being collected. Why are you trying to do this? This sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this will prevent the `Dog` instances on which the `age` setter has been called to be GCed inside the scope of where the `dogAgeMap` is defined. If you defined the `Dog.age` extension property (and thus `dogAgeMap`) in a limited scope with a limited (short) lifespan, then you are okay.

However, if that is not the case, and you need the `age` info all across you application, then `age` should just be part of the original class definition and you don't ever run into this problem.

Solution in this case

```
class Dog(val age: Int)
```

---

If you need the `age` information only in one part of your application, then a better way would be to create the lookup (the `HashMap`) only for that part, or to simply use an enriched class with `age` (or a wrapper class with `age`) instead of the `Dog` class in that part of your application. And when you are done with work there, you clean up the map or the enriched class instances. In that way no instances will leak.

---

But if you **really really** want to do it with an extension property across the whole application, and thus you need to keep the reference to the `dogAgeMap` all the time, then you need to take care of leaking memory if you have a lot of instances that you go through and set their age.

If that is your case you can use a `WeakHashMap<Dog, Int>` instead. A `WeakHashMap` only keeps weak references and it won't prevent `Dog` instances to be GCed (once your strong references are no longer retained).

```
import java.util.WeakHashMap

val dogAgeMap = WeakHashMap<Dog, Int>()
var Dog.age: Int
    get() = dogAgeMap[this] ?: 0
    set(value) {
        dogAgeMap[this] = value
    }
```

Note however, that `WeakHashMap` is a Java class and not part of Kotlin core library, so if you use Kotlin for multiplatform, this won't work. In that case you would need a `WeakHashMap` implementation (library) on each platform.

An **alternative way** to do this if your data for dogs also contains an ID for each dog, would be to use the ID as the lookup key instead. That would be possible to port to all platforms. The implementation would then change to

```
// I am using a Long here, but it could be whatever type that
// is small enough to not cause memory concerns, since
// these keys would still exist in memory because a normal HashMap is used.
class Dog(val id: Long) {}

val dogAgeMap = HashMap<Long, Int>()
var Dog.age: Int
    get() = dogAgeMap[id] ?: 0
    set(value) {
        dogAgeMap[id] = value
    }
```